# how the way to print value from java arrayList with specific column from a model in jsp file

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have a model using arrayList from get and set the value. But, i confuse to print it in jsp file.
This my code :

```
<div class="card-header" style="font-weight:bold;">
        <% Feedback fb = new Feedback(); %>
        <h3><c:out value="${fb.full_name}" /></h3>
    </div>
```

i think `<c:out value="${fb.full_name}" />` this code is wrong because no print any value on page. What should the code i write?

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign your object onto the request to make it accessible to the jstl EL expressions.

```
request.setAttribute("fb", new Feedback())
```

or

```
<c:set var="fb" scope="request" value = "${new Feedback()}"/>
```

Jstl cannot access values in the servlet code of the JSP(which is where the code in <% %> ends up) it has to be explicitly added to a supported JSTL scope such as the request, or the session.